# Wait till Visual tree is done updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am getting this error when I open dialog box on startup: `Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended.`

At the start of the application, a Login Dialog window opens at the top of a window with switchable content. By that I mean I have a window, in which content get switched out by setting a ViewModel property on main window.

I Do not get the error if i do not set the main window viewmodel, because it does not need to change anything in the view.

This is the MainView, with the switchable viewmodel:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfProject.Views.Main.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:WpfProject.ViewModels.Main"
    Title="WpfProject" Height="700" Width="1000"
    Content="{Binding ViewModel}"
    Visibility="{Binding MainWindowVisiblility}"
    xmlns:MvvmDialogs="clr-namespace:MvvmDialogs.Behaviors;assembly=MvvmDialogs"
    MvvmDialogs:DialogBehavior.DialogViewModels="{Binding Dialogs}"
    xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:WpfProject.Behaviors"

    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
>
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Behaviors:CancelCloseWindowBehavior CloseAction="{Binding CloseAction}"></Behaviors:CancelCloseWindowBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StartUpProcedureCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MainViewModel ></ViewModels:MainViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
```

The Interaction Trigger is the action that execute the dialog window.

For dialog windows i am using Mark J Feldman's way of handling dialog boxes, which can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM)

Now as suggested in the Title I would like to wait till the MainViewModel has been changed and updated the view, before opening the dialog window.

Startup procedure command:

```
private ICommand _StartUpProcedureCommand;
public ICommand StartUpProcedureCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _StartUpProcedureCommand ?? (_StartUpProcedureCommand = new Command(StartUpProcedure));
    }
}
private void StartUpProcedure()
{

    UserLoginDialog();

}
private void UserLoginDialog(IUser user = null)
{

    MainWindowVisiblility = Visibility.Hidden;
    LoginViewModel lvm=new LoginViewModel(user);
    this.Dialogs.Add(lvm);
    if (lvm.Result == null)
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();

}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for StartUpProcedureCommand? This is where a fix would be implemented.

Comment: Yeah let me just find it

Answer (score 0):

Mark's pattern for dialogs looks like a pretty ugly and poorly thought out solution to me, despite the lengthy article he has written.

You are getting a sort of deadlock on the UI thread and need to wrap the showing of the new window in `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` so that it is executed asynchronously and allows the dispatcher thread to continue processing.

Something like this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => new CustomDialogWindow {DataContext = parent.DataContext}.ShowDialog());
```

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work either, may just look for a better dialog pattern, and replace it before i get too far into the project